How to make calculation in javascript based on foreach at view form in Laravel
I want to create auto calculation in javascript but my form in foreach. So for now it only calculate once... But my form most of it is in array
here is my form view.blade code
 <!-- Retail -->
                    <div class="card-body" id="retail">
                        @foreach($tenant->tenantSpace as $tenantSpace)
                        <div class="border p-2 mt-1 mb-3 mt-lg-0 rounded">
                            <h4>Lot no: {{$tenantSpace->space->unit_no}}</h4>
                            <input type="hidden" name="tenant_space_id[]" value="{{$tenantSpace->id}}">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-text text-muted" style="font-size: 17px; ">Total Size (Sqft): &nbsp;</div>
                                        <input id="total-sqft" name="total_area[]" class="form-control total-area" type="number" placeholder="Total Size" value="{{ $tenantSpace->space->space_size }}" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- First Table -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="border p-2 mt-1 mt-lg-0 rounded">
                                                <h4>Year 1</h4>
                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table>
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr class="text-muted mb-4 text-truncate">
                                                                <th>Price PSF (RM)</th>
                                                                <th style="padding-left: 9px;">Total Price (RM)</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody style="text-align: center;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input id="rate-yr1" name="price_rate_yr1[]" type="text" class="form-control total-area" placeholder="Price PSF" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->price_rate_yr1 }}"></input>
                                                                    <input id="id" name="rate_id[]" type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="id" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->id }}"></input>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input id="monthly-rent-yr1" name="monthly_rent_yr1[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Price (RM)" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->monthly_rent_yr1 }}" readonly></input>
                                                                </td>
                                                                @error('price_rate_yr1[]')
                                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                                                @enderror
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div> <!-- end .table-responsive-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="border p-2 mt-1 mt-lg-0 rounded">
                                                <h4>Year 2</h4>
                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table>
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr class="text-muted mb-4 text-truncate">
                                                                <th>Price PSF (RM)</th>
                                                                <th style="padding-left: 9px;">Total Price (RM)</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody style="text-align: center;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input id="rate-yr2" name="price_rate_yr2[]" type="text" class="form-control total-area" placeholder="Price PSF" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->price_rate_yr2 }}"></input>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input id="monthly-rent-yr2" name="monthly_rent_yr2[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Price (RM)" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->monthly_rent_yr2 }}" readonly></input>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div> <!-- end .table-responsive-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="border p-2 mt-1 mt-lg-0 rounded">
                                                <h4>Year 3</h4>
                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table>
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr class="text-muted mb-4 text-truncate">
                                                                <th>Price PSF (RM)</th>
                                                                <th style="padding-left: 9px;">Total Price (RM)</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody style="text-align: center;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input id="rate-yr3" name="price_rate_yr3[]" type="text" class="form-control total-area" placeholder="Price PSF" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->price_rate_yr3 }}"></input>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input id="monthly-rent-yr3" name="monthly_rent_yr3[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Price (RM)" value="{{ $tenantSpace->rate->monthly_rent_yr3 }}" readonly></input>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div> <!-- end .table-responsive-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <!-- end col -->

this is my current javascript for auto calculation
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Function to calculate monthly rent for each year
        function calculateMonthlyRent(year) {
            var totalArea = parseFloat($('#total-area').val());
            var priceRate = parseFloat($('#price-rate-' + year).val());
            var monthlyRent = totalArea * priceRate;
            $('#monthly-rent-' + year).val(monthlyRent.toFixed(2));
        }

        // Bind input change event for each price input
        $('[id^=price-rate-]').on('input', function() {
            var year = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop();
            calculateMonthlyRent(year);
        });

        // Trigger calculation initially
        $('[id^=price-rate-]').each(function() {
            var year = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop();
            calculateMonthlyRent(year);
        });
    });
</script>

I expect input id=monthly-rent-yr1, id=monthly-rent-yr2 and id=monthly-rent-yr3 can be auto calculate based on the array [], for now it can only auto calculate once ...
The calculation should be
monthly_rent_yr1[]=total_area[]*price_rate_yr1[]
monthly_rent_yr2[]=total_area[]*price_rate_yr2[]
monthly_rent_yr3[]=total_area[]*price_rate_yr3[]

For more understanding, below are the picture of the output, for now what I can do is ... only 1st box (based on the picture) can make the auto calculation for the input id=monthly-rent-yr1, id=monthly-rent-yr2 and id=monthly-rent-yr3.. 2nd box(also based on the picture) the calculation not function

Please help me :(

<input id="total-area" - this is inside your loop, so you are duplicating IDs here.

Next time post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. - this is not a PHP issue so post a [mcve] with only HTML, Script and relevant frameworks

Also you can delegate on $("#retail") and use relative addressing $(this).closest('someSelector') to have a simpler event loop

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? Try to figure this out first to manage the next steps
